# css: invalid property value

Tags: html, css, syntax-error

I've got a problem and I don't know how to solve it. The line that has this invalid property value is between the 4 asterisks (or *). If you need anything else like the HTML please let me know. Everything works fine besides that.

```
.card-front, .card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    **background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,100,0.26)), url(bckg.png);**
    padding: 55px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is an image with the error on the website

[image: Here is an image with the error on the website]

Comment: `linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,100,0.26))` --> `linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,100,0.26) 0 0)`

Answer (score 1):

`rgb(0,0,100,0.26)` is not a valid rgb value. Should be `rgba(0,0,100,0.26)`

Comment: it does work, you can test it. The issue is the gradient syntax

Comment: I've tried using rgba as well, but I've got the same error.